# grub2 with serial backup

Tags: grub2, serial, headless

I just setup a headless server.  I would like to administrate this via serial, but I won't always have a serial connection plugged in.  If I configure `GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"`, grub2 will not automatically boot when my serial connection is not plugged in.  Is there any way to have serial configured as a backup in grub2 so that I can control grub2 if there is a serial connection, but so that the machine still boots otherwise?